# Get all data from indexedDB by multiple keys

Tags: indexeddb

How can I get data from indexedDB by 2 or more keys?
For example I have an images_store with image_code as index.
Say I have:

```
image_code | image_value
img_aaa000 | ###########
img_bbb111 | #######$$.#
img_ccc222 | ###5%######
img_ddd333 | #.###***###
```

I want to get data for image codes "img_bbb111" and "img_ddd333" just like when I query it from SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM images_store WHERE image_code IN ("img_bbb111","img_ddd333");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to issue multiple queries. The SQL `IN` operator is essentially syntactic sugar for `image_code = a or image_code = b`. The issue is the use of `or` here. indexedDb does not support something like `or`. So you need to issue a query for `img_bbb111` followed by a second query for `img_ddd333` and then combine the results of the two queries.

Something like this:

```html
function myOnUpgradeNeeded(event) {
   const imageStore = db.createObjectStore('images_store', ...);
   imageStore.createIndex('image_code_index', 'image_code');
}

function findImagesForCodes(db, codes) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const transaction = db.transaction('images_store');
    const store = transaction.objectStore('images_store');
    const codeIndex = store.index('image_code_index');

    const results = [];

    transaction.oncomplete = event => resolve(results);
    transaction.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);

    for (const code of codes) {
      const request = codeIndex.get(code);
      request.onsuccess = onRequestSuccess;
    }

    function onRequestSuccess(event) {
      const image = event.target.result;
      if(image) {
        results.push(image);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! Yeah looks like IDB doesn't support it. I'll be using multiple IDB.get() in this case.